# No audio in vlc player when sharing screen in discord

Tags: sound, video, vlc

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.In discord, when i'm trying to share screen in discord i can share vlc playing but my video has no sound to others.
How can i solve this?
(I think for using discord now web camera is not working properly.It has become more black and sometimes its okey but sometimes it's not.)

Comment: Can you add some more informations ?

Answer (score -1):

You normally can't stream sound on discord if you're not under W10, but here's a guide that may help you

https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/f22vz6/guide_how_to_stream_audio_to_discord_on_linux/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.